# Will RTAB-MAP work without /tf topic?

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I have some kinect bags that I'd like to try out with RTAB-MAP but they don't have a " /tf " topic.
Will RTAB-MAP work without " /tf " topic ?

Based on the answer below. I tried to use a launch file to run the `static_transform_publisher` line but I don't seem to be getting a map. The launch file is based on [rgbdslam_datasets.launch](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/master/launch/tests/rgbdslam_datasets.launch) and [2.5 Kinect](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/SetupOnYourRobot). The launch file is below:

```
<launch>

 <!-- Eg from  http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/SetupOnYourRobot - Kinect & rgbdslam_datasets.launch -->

 <!-- Choose visualization -->
   <arg name="rviz" default="true" />
   <arg name="rtabmapviz" default="false" /> 
 
  <param name="use_sim_time" type="bool" value="True"/>


<!-- TF FRAMES -->
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="world_to_map" 
    args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 /base_link /camera_link 100" />

  <group ns="rtabmap">

    <!-- Odometry -->
    <node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rgbd_odometry" name="rgbd_odometry" output="screen">
      <remap from="rgb/image"       to="/camera/rgb/image_color"/>
      <remap from="depth/image"     to="/camera/depth_registered/image_raw"/>
      <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="/camera/rgb/camera_info"/>

      <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="camera_link"/>
    </node>


 <!-- Visual SLAM -->
    <node name="rtabmap" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" output="screen" args="--delete_db_on_start">
          <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="camera_link"/>
          <param name="subscribe_depth" type="bool" value="true"/>

          <remap from="odom" to="odom"/>
          <remap from="rgb/image" to="/camera/rgb/image_color"/>
          <remap from="depth/image" to="/camera/depth_registered/image_raw"/>
          <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="/camera/rgb/camera_info"/>

          <param name="queue_size" type="int" value="10"/> 

          <!-- RTAB-Map's parameters -->
          <param name="RGBD/AngularUpdate" type="string" value="0"/>
          <param name="RGBD/LinearUpdate" type="string" value="0"/>
          <param name="Rtabmap/TimeThr" type="string" value="700"/>
          <param name="Mem/RehearsalSimilarity" type="string" value="0.45"/>
          <param name="RGBD/OptimizeFromGraphEnd" type="string" value="true"/> 

    </node>

   <!-- Visualisation  -->
    <node if="$(arg rtabmapviz)" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmapviz" name="rtabmapviz" args="-d $(find rtabmap_ros)/launch/config/rgbd_gui.ini" output="screen">
      <param name="subscribe_depth" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <param name="subscribe_laserScan" type="bool" value="false"/>
      <param name="subscribe_odom_info" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <param name="queue_size" type="int" value="30"/>
      
      <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="kinect"/>
    
      <remap from="rgb/image" to="/camera/rgb/image_color"/>
      <remap from="depth/image" to="/camera/depth_registered/image_raw"/>
      <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="/camera/rgb/camera_info"/>
      <remap from="odom" to="odom"/>
    </node>
        
  </group>
  
  <node if="$(arg rviz)" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $(find rtabmap_ros)/launch/config/rgbdslam_datasets.rviz"/>
  <node if="$(arg rviz)" pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="points_xyzrgb" args="standalone rtabmap_ros/point_cloud_xyzrgb">
    <remap from="rgb/image"       to="/camera/rgb/image_color"/>
    <remap from="depth/image"     to="/camera/depth_registered/image_raw"/>
    <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="/camera/rgb/camera_info"/>
    <remap from="cloud"           to="voxel_cloud" />
    
    <param name="queue_size" type="int" value="10"/>
    <param name="decimation" type="double" value="4"/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

The output after launching the file is attached [sum1.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14818018814776036.png) [sum2.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/1481801897878805.png).

Rqt_graph is below.

[image: image description]

`tf view_frames` says "no tf data received"

In RVIZ I changed `world` in fixed frame to `/camera_link`.  But still no map, only coordinate frame.

Sorry, not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249970/will-rtab-map-work-without-/tf-topic-?/) by [ap](https://answers.ros.org/users/3948/ap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2016-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, you should have at least transforms from `/base_link` to sensor frames. For example, you can look at this file [rgbd_launch/launch/kinect_frames.launch](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rgbd_launch/blob/indigo-devel/launch/kinect_frames.launch) to see how Kinect's frames are configured. Then to link to `/base_link`:

```
$ rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 base_link camera_link 100
$ rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0.15 0 0 0 base_link base_scan 100
```

Here the camera is 20 cm over `/base_link` and the laser is 15 cm over `/base_link`.

**EDIT**

The rgbd_slam dataset launch file assumed some defined TF in the rosbag and have a hacky solution to show both ground truth (/world->/kinect) and estimated trajectory in RVIZ at the same time. Normally, if you have standard topics recorded in your rosbag, you could follow this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/HandHeldMapping). Assuming you don't have any TF in the bag (only `/camera/rgb/image_color`, `/camera/depth_registered/image_raw` and `/camera/rgb/camera_info`):

```
$ roscore
$ rosparam set use_sim_time true
$ roslaunch rgbd_launch kinect_frames.launch
$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch
$ rosbag play --clock recorded.bag
```

Here [kinect_frames.launch](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rgbd_launch/blob/indigo-devel/launch/kinect_frames.launch) will publish `/camera_link` to rgb and depth camera optical links. By default [rtabmap.launch](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/master/launch/rtabmap.launch) uses `camera_link` as fixed frame, so nothing to change.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ap](https://answers.ros.org/users/3948/ap/) on 2016-12-14**:
Thanks for the reply. So if I understand correctly, I  would have to record a new bag file but before I record I should run the `rosrun tf static_transform_publisher  ...`   line above to get the correct transform from camera_link to base_link stored in topic /tf ? Thanks

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-12-14**:
Either record a new bag while recording these TF or launch these `static_transform_publisher` at the same time as the bag (make sure you run the bag with `--clock` option so that time in TF will be the same as the bag).

**Comment by [ap](https://answers.ros.org/users/3948/ap/) on 2016-12-15**:
Thank you, sorry to bother you. I tried the above but could not get a map. Please see edited question. Thanks

**Comment by [ap](https://answers.ros.org/users/3948/ap/) on 2016-12-20**:
Thanks, it worked great! Just had to remap `rgb_topic:=/camera/rgb/image_color`
Sorry for the confusion.